# Apache writes 6M to disk after (almost) every request

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm running a micro EC2 instance, and i've been seeing ... quite a lot of I/O usage (14+ million iops... for a webserver with barely 40 hits a day, plus spiders activity).

After playing with `iotop`, i found that Apache is writing somewhere around 6.3 megabytes, if you hit it with a browser, after a couple minutes of inactivity.

It's **not** Swap Memory usage.

Do you have any idea about what might be causing this?

**NOTE:**: I used, `iotop -a -P` to run this tests.

Answer (score 1):

If it's being written after every request, the most likely place for it to go is the logs. Have you tried comparing the output of

```
du -sh /path/to/apache/logs
```

before and after making a request, to see if the logs are growing by that 6MB?

If you're still having difficulty finding where it's writing to, try using lsof to see what files it has open.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!. Weird thing is... the size of the logfile-folder doesn't increase, at all. I'm not seeing anything weird with LSOF... honestly, i'm lost with this!.

Comment: I've figured out.... turns out that i've got APC installed. I have (no idea) why, but it's doing a lot of I/O. Thanks for your help David!

Answer (score 1):

Okay... found & fixed the problem. This issue is related to this post: [High disk I/O when cache is used?](https://serverfault.com/questions/361032/high-disk-i-o-when-cache-is-used)

It turns out that APC was using a mmaped file, which caused high I/O consumption.